# TYPO3 CMS Fluid Styled Content different behaviours with empty p element

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, fluid-styled-content

I got two TYPO3 CMS instances. One was setup with version 8.7.x and one was upgraded to 8.7.x from 7.6.x.

I created a content element with CType `textpic` containing the following text in both instances (got it from source code from ckeditor):

```html
<p>Test</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>text</p>
```

In the database, **both** `tt_content` entries look like this:

```html
<p>Test</p>

<p>text</p>
```

Now, we come to the frontend.

TYPO3 CMS which was setup with version 8.7.x renders the following HTML code:

```html
<p>Test</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>text</p>
```

TYPO3 CMS which was upgraded to version 8.7.x renders the following HTML code:

```html
<p>Test</p><p></p><p>text</p>
```

The `&nbsp;` is missing in the upgraded instance.

I use `fluid_styled_content` in both instances. Why the instances behaviour is not the same?

Comment: Are you sure that the empty line in tt_content has no space in it? Perhaps this is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something on the Typo3 core bugtracker which looks like your problem.

> With the update to 8.7.20 the `" "` in an `<p></p>` were removed witch the
>   result that many empty but needed lines/spaces were removed in the
>   frontend.

Just put this line in your TypoScript setup of your website as a temporary solution until the bug is fixed:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.innerStdWrap_all.ifBlank = &nbsp;
```

You can find the original bug here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86819

Hope that helped!